# Implementing A Favorite Button Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, favorites

I Would like to implement a `Favorite button` in my `detailVC`.

I Have a tableView with a list of restaurants in the area :

## **ResterauntTableViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class ResterauntViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var tableViewController: UITableView!
    
    // MARK : Data

var names = ["Shalvata",
                 "Markid",
                 "Litzman Bar",
                 "The Cat & The Dog",
                 "Light house",
                 "Ku"]
```

it looks like this :

[image]

Each cell has a `DetailViewController` and a favorite `button` i wish to create.

I have already set up a `button` that is changing the image if i click on the `button` and vice versa right here :

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //create a new button
        let Favoritebutton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
        //set image for button
        Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "EmptyHeart.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "FilledHeart.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        //add function for button
        Favoritebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.button(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        //set frame
        Favoritebutton.frame = CGRectMake(90, 90, 35, 35)
        
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: Favoritebutton)
        //assign button to navigationbar
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
}
```

Once `Favorite button` is clicked i want to show the item wish was clicked and set as favorite to show in another tab ( i have a tab bar project )

and of course when i quit the app it will remember my `favorites`.

i managed to do the button myself but i don't know how to create the favorite function so i would like to get some help.I couldn't find any good tutorial showing any of it either.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean when you say "...I want the `tableViewCell` of the `detailVC` to show in another tab (`FavoriteTab`)"

A table view cell belongs to a table view. I guess you mean that you want the item the user selected to be marked as a favorite, and shown on another screen.

It also isn't clear what you mean by "...show in another tab (`FavoriteTab`)". Are you using a tab bar controller, and you want to add the user's selection as an additional tab in the tab bar controller?

Comment: If you need to remember the item the user chose in your table view you can save the index (for a single section table view) or the row and section (for a sectioned table view) to UserDefaults, and then in the other view controller use the user's selection to decide which item to display. It isn't clear if your faorites tab will be in the tab bar all the time or only after the user selects a favorite, nor is it clear what your data model looks like. We can't offer much in the way of help unless you can describe your needs clearly and coherently.

Comment: Both things are the same I want the `tabelViewCell` to be shown in another tableView in addition to the main tableView , Which is in a Favorites Tab .Yes , I have a tab bar application with a 5 tabs one is a list of restaurants in the area and the other is a favoriteTab as i said.

Comment: I will Edit the question right away

Answer (score 0):

It is very broad question you are asking... 
You need some kind of persistence to save the like button action. I recommend using SQLite or Core Data to store it, and then you can read it on the `FavoriteTab`

Here is a very good tutorial [SQLite Tutorial: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift)

Here is a very good tutorial on [User Defaults](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/objective-c-to-swift-guides/nsuserdefaults-swift/)

Comment: Uh, don't you mean `Core Data`, not `Core Location`? For something simple like a single selected item Core Data/SQL seem like overkill. They are powerful, but there is a big learning curve in learning how to use them.

Comment: @adirbuilder use SQLite or Core Data, it's your choice

Comment: Or `UserDefaults` might be a better fit for such a simple persistence need.

Comment: Or UserDefaults... Your choice @adirbuilder :)

Comment: Yeah but how can I create the whole favorite function I have no idea

Comment: If you are using UserDefaults create an array that stores the indexes of the favorite items... If you go with SQLlite create a table called Favorite and store a new row each time the users marks a favorite